# How to scale a number within a given range in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to scale a number to a given range of numbers. For example, Given a range of possible number is between 0 to 86. If the program generates a number outside this range then it should scale to any number between this range. Also, If the program generates a number within the range i.e. between 0 to 86 then it should keep the original.

Comment: What would be the value of, for example, `100`? Why?

Comment: Let's see some code. What have you tried? No one should do this for you.

Comment: You didn't attach any code at all. You should at least give some input/output examples, to clarify your question

Comment: @LutzHorn: for 100 it may be any number between 0 to 86. there's no rule as of now.

Comment: @jdv: I tried with min, max range. and I think Mohit has given one solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "scale" is ambiguous in your problem statement. Maybe you want to have a number within your range that you can do by taking mode. As per your example if 100 is your number then it should become within the range 0 to 86. Then you should do it like.

```
Num = Num % 87
```

and if you have range like (min, max) then

```
Num = Num % ( max - min + 1) + min
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your wanted range of integers. Create your number. Look if the number is in range, else create new in range:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
MININT=0
MAXINT=86
given_range = range(MININT, MAXINT)
my_number = random.randint(0, 100)
wanted_number = my_number if my_number in given_range else random.randint(MININT, MAXINT)
```

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range
- https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/random.html

Comment: perfected with an example :)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no rule, I suggest to keep things simple.

Scale every number outside the range of `[0, 86]` to the fixed value of `42`. That should answer The Question™.

Comment: This is a terrible answer, and yet it fits the terrible question so well I'm reluctant to downvote.

Comment: Note that it contains [The Answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_(42)). What more could the OP desire?

Comment: A clean towel and a fresh steak.